# PS/2 to USB converting for IBM Model M not working properly

Tags: keyboard, ps2-keyboard, usb-keyboard, ibm-ps2

I have an IBM Model M keyboard with terminal connector (similar to RJ45 socket) with model number 1394108 (as image below):
[image]

I connected the wires to a PS/2 to USB converter like this images
[image]

It works but not correctly: when a key pressed one time (for example z key), it type that key code infinitely (zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz).
In the Other word, keydown works but keyup don't work.

Is this problem from the converter or is related to keyboard?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try a different keyboard to compare. It is impossible to troubleshoot the cable connection in a forum.

Comment: My own model M keyboards are connected that way and they work fine. I'd suspect the converter first if the keyboard has worked elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you tsc_chazz, is your keyboard similar to one I added its image in edit?